# Анализ текста (задание № 1 ЕГЭ)

Tags: егэ, анализ-текста

> (1) Число акционеров публичного акционерного общества (ПАО) не ограничено законом. (2) Напротив, акции закрытого акционерного общества (ЗАО) распространяются только среди его учредителей или иного заранее определенного круга лиц. (3) Число акционеров закрытого общества ограничено: их не может быть более пятидесяти.

Нужно указать два предложения, в которых верно передана **главная** информация, содержащаяся в тексте:

1. Количество акционеров ПАО не ограничено законом и может превышать пятьдесят человек.
2. Акции ЗАО распределяются только среди определенного круга лиц, которых не должно быть более пятидесяти.
3. Акции ПАО распространяются только среди его учредителей или иного заранее определенного круга лиц.
4. Определенный круг лиц, среди которых могут распределяться акции ЗАО, ограничен пределом в пятьдесят человек.
5. Акциями ЗАО могут владеть только его учредители или иной заранее определенный круг лиц.

Я не понимаю, как выполнять такие задания. На что тут нужно обращать внимание? Понятно, что предложение с неверной информацией сразу отсеивается (№ 3). Но почему, допустим, №№ 4 и 5 не являются правильным ответом?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы ответил так:

Ответ № 3 неверен.

Ответ № 5 неполный: в нем не говорится о пределе в пятьдесят человек; к тому же в нем говорится не о распространениии, а о владении акциями (возможно, это не одно и то же).

Ответ № 4 хуже, чем № 2, так как в нем неверно расставлены логические акценты.

Остаются № 1 и № 2.

Comment: Мне нравится ваш ответ. Тем не менее в ключах — 1 и 4. Почему?.. (Это можно рассматривать как риторический вопрос, хотя если у вас есть на него ответ, то буду благодарен.)